# Annotorious and Openseadragon

Tags: javascript, openseadragon, annotorious

I am working on a project that uses openseadragon for for the images. I want to use annotorious for the annotation but I am stuck on the integration of the annotorious JavaScript Api. The examples provided under the test folder of downloads doesn't work.Can anyone just help me with integration of annotorious in my project like which js files should i import?
I followed the examples and used anno.makeAnnotable() and anno.activeSelector() methods as specified but it shows anno not defined and goog not defined errors in the console

Comment: I followed the examples and used anno.makeAnnotable() and anno.activeSelector() methods as specified but it shows anno not defined and goog not defined errors in the console

Comment: Actually I solved it and the Annotorious example works for me but when I added the js and css files to my project and the example code it shows "uncaught exception: Error: Annotorious does not support this media type in the current version or build configuration."  Can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the Annotorious folks? They might not be checking Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes I got it working thank you